# Complicated MySQL sorting for competition position

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table for competitions called `users`. Now, I want to be able to make a select statement that sorts this table by `post_comp DESC, posted_last ASC`. After this sort, whoever is returned first is #1, second row is #2 etc etc. However, I want to take this further and return the position of a specific user in the table. Now, each user has their own id, `zbid`. I also need to add `WHERE cid=3 AND post_comp>0` to the end of the query.

This is what I have tried:

`SELECT u.zbid,u.post_comp, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row, IF(u.zbid=123,1,0) AS me FROM users u, (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE cid=3 AND post_comp > 0 ORDER BY u.post_comp DESC, u.posted_last ASC`

Now what that does is return the following:
 `zbid`, `post_comp`, `row`, `me`
where `me` is 1 if it is the row I specifically want to return, and 0 otherwise. So if I am looking for the position of the user with `zbid=123`, it sorts the table, brings all the data back to me, and wherever the user with `zbid=123` is, will also return a `me=1` result. `row` denotes the user's position in the competition.

Now, I this works fine, only problem is that it returns all of these rows, and I only want it to return the one row with `me=1`. I tried appending another `ORDER BY me DESC LIMIT 1` to the very end but that messed up the previous ordering and didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT u.zbid,u.post_comp, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row, 
         IF(u.zbid=123,1,0) AS me 
  FROM users u, (SELECT @curRow := 0) r 
  WHERE cid=3 AND post_comp > 0 
  ORDER BY u.post_comp DESC, u.posted_last ASC
) temp 
WHERE me=1
```